# how to use Options in PDF module in play framework

Tags: playframework, pdf-generation

I want to user HEADER_TEMPLATE option. i have given like below but play throws an error Template not found

```
public class Design extends Controller {
public static void renderPDFGen()
    {
    Options options = new Options();
    options.HEADER_TEMPLATE = "/design/renderPDFHeader";
    options.filename = "Invoice";
renderPdf(options);
    }

    public static void renderPDFHeader()
        {
            render();
        }
}
```

What could be the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Do:

```
 public static void renderPDFHeader()
 {
    //calculate the contents for the pdf
    String var1, var2;

    //create Options helper
    PDF.Options options = new PDF.Options();
    options.filename="myfile.pdf";
    //etc...

    //render
    renderPdf(options, var1, var2); //note it's renderPDF, not render
 }
```

You get the *Template not found* most likely becuase Play tries to find "/views/design/renderPdfHeader.html" and it's not there

Comment: I am getting filename as excpected but i'm unable to load the HEADER_TEMPLATE file

Comment: i changed the path to options.HEADER_TEMPLATE = "/design/renderPDFHeader.html"; but not found error occurs

Comment: @Arasu if you are setting the options properly and the template exists, it should work... double check the paths

Comment: I have given absolute path inside and outside of my play application but error occurs